# "Identifier references" in C# regions

Tags: c#, reference, documentation, identifier, region

The triple slash comments allows to embed "strong" references to identifiers. For exemple :

```
/// <summary>
/// See the method <see cref="Foo(int, string)" /> for more info.
/// </summary>
```

When refactoring identifiers, such as method or class names, it automatically updates the comments as well.

Is there any a way to do this with the "label" for a code region ? This does not seem to work :

```
#region Methods for <see cref="IEnumerable{T}"/> implementation

// ...

#endregion Methods for <see cref="IEnumerable{T}"/> implementation
```

Which causes maintainability issues when referencing identifiers in code region labels.

Comment: The best way to use regions is to forget they ever existed :) remember: if a class is so big you "need" regions, that class does to much. As for the question, no, there's none; you are mixing up a Visual Studio-only feature with a compiler feature

Comment: If you consider that any class that can benefit from regions is "too big", then you might just trash the whole .NET framwork...